# How to avoid startup latency for Azure Table Storage/Cosmos DB Table API on .Net Core

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-cosmosdb-tables

Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips) suggests to use `await client.OpenAsync();` to avoid startup latency to Cosmos DB. This seems to be only applicable to SQL API. I try to use Table API and could not manage to do the same. My first request executes in 1500 ms and subsequent takes only 40, so that would be a very nice improvement.

I had tried both `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` to connect, but did not find any way of doing that. The only thing I can think of is doing a "dummy" request that for sure does not return anything instead to achieve the same goal.

Is there any better way to initialize the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to query anything that you know exists.

Any call using the client will initialise the connection and do the (approximately) 8 requests that CosmosDB needs.

Reading the database account would be the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: I thought it's best to query something that does not exists? No overhead sending the data. Not sure also what do you mean by reading the database account

Comment: A direct read will do just fine. Do NOT do a query because depending on whether a partition key is specified or not you might end up wasting resources. The DatabaseAccount is the safest thing to read directly and guaranteed to be there directly. You don't really wanna handle Resource Not Found exceptions.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik DatabaseAccount is the root resource when you create a Cosmos DB resource in Azure. It's where all your Databases and Collections hang from. It's a very think file. I have bad experiences with exceptions using the Cosmos DB SDK (v2). Directly reading something that exists is faster than something that doesn't (at least it was when I tested).

Comment: I use Table API so I don't do any of these connections directly. I use `CloudStorageAccount` and `CloudTableClient` so cannot quite figure out the way to do what you suggest

Comment: Oh I see. Then yeah, using the `CloudTableClient` to query something that doesn't exist will work just fine.